# class based view in django

Tags: python, django, oop

I am trying to understand class based view concepts in django. Before that i should know the function call and return statement.I would like to know what it does which I mentioned below code. I know that is about to call parent class function. what should it return. Can anyone explain this concepts with example. Thanks in advance.

```
class Foo(Bar):
  def baz(self, arg):
    return super(Foo, self).baz(arg)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am explaining this with example.

I am creating two classes which one is `inheriting` from other.

```
class Parent(object):

    def implicit(self):
        print "PARENT implicit()"

class Child(Parent):
    pass

dad = Parent()
son = Child()

>>>dad.implicit()
>>>son.implicit()
"PARENT implicit()"
"PARENT implicit()"
```

This creates a `class` named `Child` but says that there's nothing new to define in it. Instead it will `inherit` all of its behavior from `Parent`.

Now next example

```
class Parent(object):

    def override(self):
        print "PARENT override()"

class Child(Parent):

    def override(self):
        print "CHILD override()"

dad = Parent()
son = Child()

>>>dad.override()
>>>son.override()
"PARENT override()"
"CHILD override()"
```

Even though `Child` `inherits` all behaviour from `Parent`, `Child.override` messages because `son` is an `instance` of `Child` and `Child` overrides that function by defining its own version

Now next example,

```
class Parent(object):

    def altered(self):
        print "PARENT altered()"

class Child(Parent):

    def altered(self):
        print "CHILD, BEFORE PARENT altered()"
        super(Child, self).altered()
        print "CHILD, AFTER PARENT altered()"

dad = Parent()
son = Child()

>>>dad.altered()
>>>son.altered()
"PARENT altered()"
"CHILD, BEFORE PARENT altered()"
"PARENT altered()"
"CHILD, AFTER PARENT altered()"
```

Here we can find `super(Child, self).altered()`, which is aware of `inheritance` and will get the `Parent` `class`.(Not caring overriding)

Hope this helps

**Update.**.In `python3`

`super().altered()` can use instead of `super(Child, self).altered()`

For more http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex44.html

Comment: okay fine and thanks. One more doubt... If two classes inherited means what it should be called... see like class C(A,B):

Comment: same thing super(Foo, self).baz1(arg) # baz1 is second  class method

Comment: @karnaf classes used a simple MRO scheme: when looking up a method, base classes were searched using a simple depth-first left-to-right scheme.So here First check in `class A`, if not then `class B`

Comment: To clarify your doubt about multiple inheritance  http://python-history.blogspot.in/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: ya i post simple example

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo(Bar):#here Bar is your super class, you inherit  super class methods 
  def baz(self, arg):#this class method 
    return super(Foo, self).baz(arg)# here super is mentioned as  super class of Foo .baz(arg) is you call the super user method baz(arg)
```

so u need to create super class like

```
class BAR(object):
   def baz(self,arg):
       c=10+20
       return c
```

simple example for two base class

```
class bar(object):
  def baz(self, arg):
    print"this is bar class" 

class bar1(object):
  def baz1(self,arg):
    print "this is bar1 class"         
class Foo(bar,bar1):
  def baz(self, arg):
    super(Foo, self).baz1(arg)  
    super(Foo, self).baz(arg)

a=Foo()
a.baz("hai")
```

Comment: what should it return when I mentioned super(Foo, self).baz(arg) in return statement